# Is there a way to enable ScrollBar in CodeBehind in Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-scrollview, android-scrollbar

I have written a **custom scrollBar** in native android. **I was able to display the scroll bar in native Android** there by setting the below code in the layout.xml file.

```
android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
```

Now I am porting that to Xamarin.Android. Everything is fine except the scroll bar. **How can I display the scroll bar** here in Xamarin.Android. Any one having idea on how to do this in code behind?

I **tried setting the View.HorizontalScrollBarEnabled and View.VerticalScrollBarEnabled properties** in my CustomScrollView constructor. Also have tried overriding the properties and made it true always. But it didnt work for me. I have written my **CustomScrollViewer extending from FrameLayout**. What am I doing wrong? Or Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

The attribute comes from `android.view.View` and is also accessible through `setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled` and `setVerticalScrollBarEnabled`.

These two methods are translated into properties in Xamarin.Android called `HorizontalScrollBarEnabled` and `VerticalScrollBarEnabled`.

Comment: I have already tried this. I tried setting these propertied in my CustomScrollView constructor. Also have tried overriding the property and made it true always. But it didnt work for me. I have written my CustomScrollViewer extending from FrameLayout. What am I doing wrong? Or Is there any other way?